# How can I hide component when I use ng-zorro?

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

I use Angular 7 and ng-zorro, I want to hide sidebar when I click on the login button.

I have tried this `"[(nzVisible)]="isVisible"`.  But it is not working.

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
>   Can't bind to 'nzVisible' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.`enter code here`

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! can you provide the whole element you want to hide? did you try `[hidden]="!isVisible"` or `ngIf="isVisible"`

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried all of them and it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add `*ngIf="condition"`

**working Example [ng-zorro-antd-start](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-zorro-antd-start-cmaxbz?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

```html
    <button nz-button *ngIf="false" nzType="primary" >Primary</button>
        <---hides component
    <button nz-button nzType="primary" >Primary</button>
```